# Oracle SQL Query to find records having particular status having maximum date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write Oracle sql query to get the output like below.Both Start and End Date are DATE data type.I have a file like this

```
ApName DbName Status StartDate EndDate
A1    A11   Success 8/3/2016 8/3/2016
A1    A11   Failed  8/3/2016 8/3/2016
A2    A22   Success 8/2/2016 8/2/2016
A3    A33   Success 8/2/2016 8/2/2016
A4    A44   Failed  8/2/2016 8/2/2016 
A4    A44   Failed  8/2/2016 8/2/2016
A4    A44   Success 8/3/2016 8/3/2016 
A5    A55   Failed  8/3/2016 8/3/2016
A5    A55   Failed  8/3/2016 8/3/2016
A2    A22   Success 8/3/2016 8/3/2016
```

I need output where apname and dbname have success and fail or only failed status.I dont want apname and dbname where the status is success only. All this condition shouldbe applied for  maximum date(e.g., 8/3/2016 based on the input file)

```
ApName DbName Status StartDate EndDate
  A1    A11   Success 8/3/2016 8/3/2016
  A1    A11   Failed  8/3/2016 8/3/2016
  A5    A55   Failed  8/3/2016 8/3/2016
  A5    A55   Failed  8/3/2016 8/3/2016
```

Comment: Where's your SQL query?  Please post it so that we can help you fix whatever is not working correctly.

Comment: I don't see how the results follow from the explanation.

Comment: Why `A4` is not in the resultset ? It has both "Failed" and "Success"...

Comment: A4 and A44 has only success status.So i dont want the records having only status as success even though date is latest date

Comment: @Naresh - How difficult is it to re-read your own input data before commenting something that directly contradicts it? You want free help but can't spend a few seconds to look at your input?

Comment: actually i am trying to find records having failed status and maximum date , based on this result i need to search for entire table again. I am not able to write this query.select APP_NAME,db_name,to_date(end_time,'DD-MON-YY') from backup_status where status='FAILED'  and   to_date(end_time,'DD-MON-YY') = ( select to_date(max(end_time),'DD-MON-YY') from backup_status) group by app_name, db_name,to_date(end_time,'DD-MON-YY').Froim this query i got all failed status latest records. this query result i need to search for any success or failed status

Comment: Why do you need to search the entire table again? What is the desired result? If you can't explain it clearly, posting a query that DOESN'T do what you need won't be very helpful.

Comment: From my understanding, for records with the enddate equal to the maximum enddate in the table (not partitioned), if a row exists for that apname with the status = 'Failed', then return all rows for that apname for that date.  That's what I tried to post below...

Comment: sorry i have updated with correct statement..Apologies.

Comment: @mathguy : I need output where apname and dbname have success and failed or only failed status.Since the above query i got is only failed status. now this records needs to search with table again to find whether it has any success records also.,

Comment: OK, let's see if I understand... still not clear on something. So, first you only look at all the rows that have end_date equal to maximum date, and you choose the apname, dbname which have a row with status FAILED and end date equal to maximum date. Then for these apname, dbname you show all the rows (failed and success) - ONLY for the maxdate, or for ALL the dates in the past? Still not clear from your explanation or sample (because in the sample, the ones that are picked don't have older rows in the input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Status is either 'Success' or 'Failed', it should do the job :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT a.* , 
    count(distinct Status) over (partition by a.AppName, trunc(a.EndDate)) as  statusCnt, 
    max(endDate) over(partition by a.AppName) as lastDate
    FROM your_table a
)b
WHERE trunc(b.lastDate) = trunc(b.EndDate) AND (statusCnt > 1 OR Status = 'Failed');
```

I may misinterpret the part regarding "maximum date" though. My query compares maximum date for each `AppName`, not overall maximum date.

Comment: Thank u so much for ur efforts.actually i need overall maximum date not appname max date.i am trying to edit ur query and working on it.I got the result but some records which are not reequired are also coming.

Comment: SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT a.* , 
    count(distinct Status) over (partition by a.app_name,a.db_name,a.backup_type, a.env_name,trunc(a.end_time)) as  statusCnt, 
    max(end_time) over(partition by a.App_Name, a.db_name,a.backup_type,a.env_name) as lastDate
    FROM backup_status a
)b
WHERE trunc(b.lastDate) = trunc(b.end_time) AND (statusCnt > 1 OR Status = 'FAILED') ) where to_date(end_time,'DD-MON-YY') = ( select to_date(max(end_time),'DD-MON-YY') from backup_status)

Comment: Thanks a1ex07.its working...

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you want to return all rows for a given `apname` if there is at least a single status for `failed` on the max date?

If so, this should get you going in the right direction using `max over`:

```
select t.* 
from yourtable t join (
    select apname, enddate, status, max(enddate) over () maxenddate
    from yourtable
) t2 on t2.apname = t.apname and 
    t2.maxenddate = t.enddate and
    t2.status = 'Failed'
```

---

An alternative approach with `exists`:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
where enddate = (select max(enddate) from yourtable) 
    and exists (
        select 1
        from yourtable t2
        where t.apname = t2.apname 
            and t.enddate = t2.enddate 
            and t2.status = 'Failed'
)
```

Comment: These queries do not return all the rows for a given apname (and dbname) if there is at least one FAILED on the max date - they only return the rows that have an enddate equal to maxenddate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using analytic functions, but no joins.

**Assumptions**:

The dates may contain a time element (time-of-day). The requirement is to return rows for the apps/databases that have at least one row with FAILED status and EndDate on the same day as the max of all enddates in the table (but possibly an earlier time-of-day).

For those app/database pairs, return ALL the rows from the table. (If the requirement was to return only the rows from the max date, the problem would be easier.)

**Query**:

```
with
     inputs ( ApName, DbName, Status, StartDate, EndDate ) as (
       select 'A1', 'A11', 'Success', to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A1', 'A11', 'Failed' , to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A2', 'A22', 'Success', to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A3', 'A33', 'Success', to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A4', 'A44', 'Failed' , to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A4', 'A44', 'Failed' , to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A4', 'A44', 'Success', to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all 
       select 'A5', 'A55', 'Failed' , to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A5', 'A55', 'Failed' , to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A2', 'A22', 'Success', to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('8/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
     ),
     prep ( apname, dbname, status, startdate, enddate, fdate, mdate ) as (
       select apname, dbname, status, startdate, enddate,
              max(case when status = 'Failed' then enddate end) over   
                                                           (partition by apname, dbname),
              max(enddate) over ()
       from   inputs
     )
select apname, dbname, status, startdate, enddate
from   prep
where  fdate >= trunc(mdate)
;
```

**Output**:

```
APNAME DBNAME STATUS  STARTDATE  ENDDATE
------ ------ ------- ---------- ----------
A1     A11    Failed  2016-08-03 2016-08-03
A1     A11    Success 2016-08-03 2016-08-03
A5     A55    Failed  2016-08-03 2016-08-03
A5     A55    Failed  2016-08-03 2016-08-03

4 rows selected.
```